# uniquess of solutions for the first-order autonomous system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $V$ be a smooth function from $U\to \Bbb{R}^n$ (where $U$ is an open subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$), the autonomous system given below:

$$\dot{y}^i(t) = V^i(y^1(t),...,y^n(t))\\y^i(t_0) = c^i$$

Exist a unique solution agree on their common domain.

The uniqueness means if $\gamma:I\to \Bbb{R^n}$ is one solution, and $\sigma:J\to \Bbb{R}^n$ is another solution (that satisfies the same initial condition), then we know $\gamma(t) = \sigma(t)$ for $I\cap J$.

The proof of this lemma uses the comparison theorem, to compare two solutions (may with different initial condition but same domain) then conclude they must be the same.

The question is why it's possible that there exist two different solutions to the initial value problem with different domains $I$ and $J$? Is there some example to illustrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove uniqueness, you can’t suppose *a priori* that two distinct solutions have the same interval of definition. However, as soon as you have proven that two solutions coincide in a neighborhood of a point and that is true for any point, then you have proven global uniqueness and therefore that the intervals of definition are the same.